# Can I access the HTML el (button) from an Ember {{action}}?

Tags: ember.js

I have the need to act on the HTML element which triggers an Ember action.

The scenario is simple, let's say I have multiple rows of items, each having an action that pulls some data via an ajax. I want to disable that particular element until the ajax request has completed.

I checked `this` property but it refers to the Component Class.

So in the below markup, I'd like to capture the  element in my component class.

```
<td><button {{action 'cancel' transaction}} class="btn-danger btn">Cancel</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a default way to disable actions in Ember.

You could do it in several ways:

1) With CSS and bound controller properties.

```
a.is-inactive {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Then you must bind the className to the controller property (Inactive).

```
<a {{action 'cancel'}} {{bind-attr class="isInactive:is-inactive"}}
```

2) You could check in your route action that your actions is disabled. Use any specific controller to save the application state.

```
  cancel: function() {
       var controller = this.controller;
       if ( controller.get('pendingAction') ) return;

       controller.set('pendingAction', true);
       this.ajax(...., function() {
         ....
         controller.set('pendingAction', false);
       }, function() {
         ....
         controller.set('pendingAction', false);
       });

    }
```

3) Built your own way..

I have discussed this case at the [discourse forum](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/blocking-actions-and-user-events-until-promise-resolution/4936).